# Howto setup EtherChannel in between two cisco switch 2960

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, etherchannel

I suddenly must configure two cisco switch 2960s within the same network, basically the idea is that through two cables they will physically be connected but logically, in each switch, two ports must look like one and be aggregated.

What should I do? I do not know much about Cisco and Switches.

Any recommendation?

Comment: I guess I must create a port channel interface into each switch and after that i should add the interfaces (2 from each Switch) to the port channel?

Answer (score 1):

Please Please Please read through Cisco documentation. It's freely accessible and easy to follow: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6406/products_installation_and_configuration_guides_list.html

Select the switch with your corresponding IOS version.

But to point you in the right direction you will have to add the ports to a channel-group.